# /bin/sh: 1: apk: not found (when using jenkins/agent:latest-jdk11)

Tags: docker

I have this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM  jenkins/agent:latest-jdk11
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
```

But when I try and build it I get:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM  jenkins/agent:latest-jdk11
 ---> 6f9ed88cf9cc
Step 2/2 : RUN apk --no-cache add curl
 ---> Running in 2f0f9c1279b6
/bin/sh: 1: apk: not found
```

As I understand `apk` is the package management for Alpine images. Looking at the base image:

```
docker inspect jenkins/agent:latest-jdk11
```

I see the following labels:

```
    "Labels": {
        "Description": "This is a base image, which provides the Jenkins agent executable (agent.jar)",
        "Vendor": "Jenkins project",
        "Version": "4.10",
        "org.opencontainers.image.description": "This is a base image, which provides the Jenkins agent executable (agent.jar)",
        "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "MIT",
        "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-agent",
```

At that location there is indeed an alpine version of the image:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-agent/blob/master/11/alpine/Dockerfile

but apparently that is not what [jenkins/agent:latest-jdk11](https://hub.docker.com/layers/jenkins/agent/latest-jdk11/images/sha256-980d72b46ee66f1fd5a6b62c09b8e0d87ff61b3ba0a7f31e7233bd870402b4d0?context=explore) is based on. So how do I find out which distro [jenkins/agent:latest-jdk11](https://hub.docker.com/layers/jenkins/agent/latest-jdk11/images/sha256-980d72b46ee66f1fd5a6b62c09b8e0d87ff61b3ba0a7f31e7233bd870402b4d0?context=explore) is?

Comment: The image names on https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/slave contain Debian code names (Buster, Stretch, etc) so ... probably Debian. There is an Alpine-based variant there, too. In the general case, there is no guarantee that you get a package manager with your Docker image, though for this use case that's probably reasonable to assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But at that location there is also a Debian version and a Windows version. The one with the latest-jdk11 tag is a Debian version. You can see the OS version with this command

```
docker run --rm jenkins/agent:latest-jdk11 cat /etc/os-release
```

which shows that it's Debian Bullseye.

To get the alpine version, you can use the `latest-alpine-jdk11` tag.